# How should I update existing table in the SQL Server database via C# and Windows forms?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to use Windows Forms and C# to implement a Database application which consists of the following tables:

`Student` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] 
(
    [Id]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [MyId] AS ('S' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT([varchar](5), [Id]), (2))) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

`Class` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class] 
(
    [Id]      INT          NOT NULL,
    [Teacher] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Grade]   INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

`StudentClassCombo`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentClassCombo]  
(
    [ClassID]   INT NOT NULL,
    [StudentID] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [ClassFK] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ClassID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Class] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [StudentFK] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([StudentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Student] ([Id])
);
```

I have a Windows forms interface through which I can assign students to classes.

[image]

I want to ensure that when the a student that has already been assigned to a class is re-assigned to a different class. the previous student-class assignment should be overwritten with the new one. In the case above, if Student ID 1 is already assigned to Class ID 1. But if the user decides to re-assign Student ID 1 to Class ID 2, the existing StudentClassCombo entry of 1-1 should be changed to 1-2.

I have written the following code to perform this update but I am encountering an exception:

```
string UpdateQuery = @"UPDATE dbo.StudentClassCombo SET"
                      + " Class.ID as ClassId, Student.Id as StudentId FROM dbo.Class, dbo.Student" +
                      " WHERE Class.Grade=@Grade and Student.Name LIKE @StudentName";


using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand Insertcmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateQuery, connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    Insertcmd.Parameters.Add("@Grade", SqlDbType.Int);
    Insertcmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

    foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in StudentsList.CheckedItems)
    {
        Insertcmd.Parameters["@Grade"].Value = int.Parse(ClassNames.Text);
        Insertcmd.Parameters["@StudentName"].Value = eachItem.SubItems[1].Text.ToString();
                    
        Insertcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

The exception I am seeing now is as follows:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

How should I update the `StudentClassCombo` entries?

Comment: In a TSQL `update` statement you `set` column values with `=`, not `as`. Are you sure that `UpdateQuery` is what you want to execute for `Insertcmd`?

Comment: Be careful saying "is assigned to a different class *at another time*" as it's confusing/ambiguous between whether the time means the "scheduled start time of the class" ie 1pm every Tuesday, or "the moment at which the student is assigned to a class" ie the user clicked the save button at 3:47pm on Jan 1 2021

Comment: @HABO Thank you for the response. _Are you sure that UpdateQuery is what you want to execute for Insertcmd?_ You are right...it isn't correct

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you for the response. I shall update my question.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

You should first executenonquery this:

```
UPDATE StudentClassCombo SET ClassId = @ClassId WHERE StudentId =@StudentId
```

..and capture the return value from ExecuteNonQuery

If the return value is 0, no records were updated (there is no student with that ID), run the following insert instead:

```
INSERT StudentClassCombo (ClassId,StudentId) VALUES(@ClassId,@StudentId)
```

You seem to already know how to add parameters to sql commands etc so I'll skip that part

Put a unique index on StudentId

If Class:Student is 1:Many (as you imply) it would be more typical to put ClassId as a column of Student table than have a middleman table, unless that middle table stores other relevant data than just the class and student id

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `ClassId` and `StudentId` belong to separate tables for me. Wouldn't I need a subquery to obtain assignments of `ClassId` and `StudentId`?

Comment: Your front end app should know the ID; you should e.g. `SELECT CONCAT(Grade, ' - ', Teacher) as ClassName, Id FROM Class` and load that into a datatable, set the `Combo.DataSource = theDatatable` and set the `DisplayMember` to `"ClassName"` and the `ValueMember` to `"ID"`.. Now your user sees "Beta = 11" in the combo but when they pick it, you can ask the combo for `classCombo.SelectedValue` and it will be "1" which is the ID of the Class, for insert/update into StudentClassCombo.

Comment: In short: make sure the app downloads both the ID and the name, show the user the name and use the relevant ID they pick. Controls like combos have ways of specifying "show this column, but when I asked for the selected value, give me that other column"

Comment: I have this code when I am populating the combo-box: `ClassNames.DisplayMember = "Grade"; ClassNames.ValueMember = "Id";`

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track then. Just ask for the SelectedValue if you want the ID. Set the style to DropDownList too

Comment: What about the Student ID? I am displaying Student names in a list view. When the user checks the name of the Student, I want the corresponding ID to be referenced and recorded in the database.

Comment: Why can you not apply the same technique? (Pull the ID and the name, show the name, use the related ID). If you can't find a way doing it with ListView (it's a generally hard-to-use control), use a CheckedListBox; it has a datasource etc

Comment: Personally wouldn't bother with two separate batches. Do it in one batch with `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` like Aaron Bertrand shows https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern

Comment: MERGE would be more portable